# Captioned figure in frontmatter causes error when using floatrow package with "facing"

Tags: floats, captions, floatrow, front-matter

I am writing a two-sided document with margins (based on the [kaobook-class](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook/)) and would like to add a figure to the front matter. However, when adding a captioned figure, the compiler throws an "undefined control sequence" error, claiming not to know basic commands within the `figure` environment.

I managed to trace the issue back to the `floatrow` package, which requires the `facing` option to be turned on, as the document is two-sided (otherwise, the captions would always be on the same side of the figures, but they need to swap depending if they are on an odd or even page). So this option has to stay on.

Curiously, I also noticed that if the `pagenumbering` is manually set to `arabic` before or within the figure environment, the issue is resolved. But unfortunately, I would like to numbering to be roman, and changing it back to `roman` immediately after the figure environment doesn't work. (Removing the caption works as well, but, of course that's not an option either.)

Here is an MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\floatsetup[figure]{% Captions for figures
    facing=yes,%
    margins=hangright,% Put captions in the margins
    capposition=beside,%
    capbesideposition={bottom,right},%
    capbesideframe=yes,%
    capbesidewidth=\marginparwidth,% Width of the caption equal to the width of the margin
    floatwidth=\textwidth,% Width of the figure equal to the width of the text
}%

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{figure}[hb]
    % \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{It's the letter A.}
    \label{fig:sample_image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The aux file contains `\gdef\@@FBset@{\global\c@FBcnti}` which is the source of the error.  This was written by floatrow (using `\string\c@FBcnt\thepage`) but `\c@FBcnti` was never defined.  My advice is to not use floatrow (ever).

Comment: Floatrow creates the counter FBcnt and is tryting to set it to `\thepage`.  However, even `\setcounter{FBcnt}{\thepage}` won't work when using roman numerals, and `\setcounter{FBcnt}{arabic{page}}` won't work unless you add `\let\arabic=\relax` to `\protected@write`, nor is `\arabic{page}` unique.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I think I start to understand. Is there any way to hack this? Because unfortunately, I cannot just stop using `floatrow` as it's fairly well incorporated into the template that I am using. I would have to find an alternative that offers the same functionality. Is there any way to find out what `FBcnt` does? I could not find it in the documentation. Maybe I could set it to some arbitrary value before the figure, like `-1` or `0`, and then reset it afterwards?

Comment: The problem will require a rewrite of floatrow.  The way `\protected@write` works, `\thepage` is not expanded until the bottom of the page on which it is printed (about the same time as the header and footer).

Comment: I see, thank you. In the meantime, I had another idea, but didn't manage to get it to work properly yet: I swap from roman to arabic page numbers on the relevant page, but then I use `\ofoot*{\roman{page}}` from the `scrlayer-scrpage` package to replace the default page number with a custom text, and then use the `afterpage` package to reset the page numbering back to roman (all while saving the page numbers in a new counter to to allow for continuous counting). Generally, this works, but I'm also using a custom `pagelayout` which causes the `\ofoot` command to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a new counter `abspage` to avoid `\thepage` altogether.  It also uses the aux file to determine which page the float wound up on.

No idea why you want [hb], but it works.  Note that `\clearpage` will turn all floats still in the queue to [p].

The `\hfill` is used to place the `\rlap` or `\llap` at the right edge of the text area.  It will also push images to the left edge.  Instead of `\centering` you can use `\hspace*{\fill}` or `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for valign
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% random text
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\def\bottomfraction{0.7}% default is 0.3

\newcounter{abspage}
\setcounter{abspage}{1}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\stepcounter{abspage}}

\newcommand{\MCright}[2][c]{% #1=t, c or b (optional), #2=\caption{...}
  \hfill\rlap{\hskip\marginparsep
    \begin{minipage}[#1]{\marginparwidth}
      \vskip-\abovecaptionskip
      #2
      \vskip-\belowcaptionskip
      \hrule height0pt
    \end{minipage}}}

\newcommand{\MCleft}[2][c]{% #1=t, c or b (optional), #2=\caption{...}
  \hfill\llap{\begin{minipage}[#1]{\marginparwidth}
    \vskip-\abovecaptionskip
    #2
    \vskip-\belowcaptionskip
    \hrule height0pt
  \end{minipage}\hskip\marginparsep\hskip\textwidth}    
    \newcounter{MCindex}
    \renewcommand{\theMCindex}{\roman{MCindex}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\margincaption}[2][c]{% #!=t,c or b (optional), #2=\caption{...}
  \stepcounter{MCindex}%
  \protected@write{\@auxout}{\let\theabspage\relax}%
    {\string\gdef\string\MCpage\theMCindex{\theabspage}}%
  \@ifundefined{MCpage\theMCindex}%
    {\ifodd\value{abspage} \MCright[#1]{#2}%
      \else \MCleft[#1]{#2}\fi}%
    {\ifodd\csname MCpage\theMCindex\endcsname\relax \MCright[#1]{#2}%
      \else \MCleft[#1]{#2}\fi}%
  \par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{figure}[hb]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=T]{example-image-a}%
    \margincaption[t]{\caption{It's the letter A.}\label{fig:sample_image}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[hb]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, valign=T]{example-image-a}%
    \margincaption[t]{\caption{It's the letter A.}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-3]% second float to bottom of page

\mainmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, impressive. Thanks a lot! So if I understand correctly, this is basically a workaround to avoid using `floatrow` altogether? Is it possible to align the caption with the top of the figure? The `[hb]` was just an arbitrary remnant that I forgot to remove for the MWE, sorry.

Comment: [valign=t] and [t] for `\indludegraphics` and `minipage`, respectively.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `valign=t`, but for some reason, I have to set the minipage alignment to `c`, otherwise, the caption will start a few mm below the figure top.

Comment: The problem with [c] is that extra lines build both up and down.  I revised the solution so [valign=T] and [t] work well.  `\caption` must put the baseline at the very top.